# Android GZIP decompression result is cut off

Tags: android, gzip, httpclient

I am receiving a JSON response from our server and it is compressed using gzip. I tried many methods of decoding the data and spitting out the result however all of them lead to the data being cut short. I am not getting the full JSON response.

I used the below as per google examples and am confident it should work. am I missing anyhting else?

```
API.client.addResponseInterceptor(new HttpResponseInterceptor() {
         public void process(final HttpResponse response, final HttpContext context) throws HttpException, IOException {
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            Header contentEncodingHeader = entity.getContentEncoding();
            if (contentEncodingHeader != null) {
               HeaderElement[] codecs = contentEncodingHeader.getElements();
               for (int i = 0; i < codecs.length; i++) {
                  if (codecs[i].getName().equalsIgnoreCase(API.GZIP)) {
                     response.setEntity(new GzipDecompressingEntity(response.getEntity()));
                     return;
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      });


static class GzipDecompressingEntity extends HttpEntityWrapper {
          public GzipDecompressingEntity(final HttpEntity entity) {
             super(entity);
          }

          @Override
          public InputStream getContent() throws IOException, IllegalStateException {
             // the wrapped entity's getContent() decides about repeatability
             InputStream wrappedin = wrappedEntity.getContent();
             return new GZIPInputStream(wrappedin);
          }

          @Override
          public long getContentLength() {
             // length of ungzipped content is not known
             return -1;
          }
}
```

And I get he response and string to return using the below.

```
response = API.client.execute(postMethod);
        Log.i(LOG_TAG_GENERAL, "STATUS CODE: " + String.valueOf(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()));

        BasicResponseHandler handler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        resp = handler.handleResponse(response);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You might try switching to [`HttpURLConnection`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html). It offers transparent GZip encoding. It's also the new Googly recommendation for doing HTTP operations on Android.

Comment: i rewrote the method to use HttpURLConnection however I still am having the same problem. The server is using https however authentication and all seem to be working since I am retrieving a JSON response (just not all of it). Also by reading the documentation it seems that HttpURLConnection should transparently create an HttpsURLConnection object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `entity.consumeContent()` to ensure everything is processed. Better  call the execute method that takes a handler paramter, it does the right thing. Something like this:

```
String responseStr = httpclient.execute(get, responseHandler);
```

For the record, the `HttpURLConnection` API sucks.

Comment: so to the postmethod I added getEntity().consumeContent() and I added  a <String> responsehandler directly to the execute method. I then printed out the response and the response string still gets cut off. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so thank you Mark Murphy (not sure if its you) and Nikolay. I used both of your suggestions and still received same errors. however because of this I focused more on the actual content of the result. Basically the returned result was too large to simply spit to the log which I assumed might be the case but also the length of the JSONArray generated was shorter however this was due to a server-side change, therefore I was being too narrow minded and made a junior mistake.

I am interested tho on why HttpURLConnection "sucks". I mean visually its very ugly opening a connection with input and output streams etc. I stuck with just using a ResponseInterceptor however my code for the HttpURLConnection will remain commented out and not deleted until I am certain it "sucks".

Comment: I said the _API_ sucks. It's just one class with a hundred getter/setter methods, You have to use (and remember) magic properties  to change behaviour, the whole `doInput/Output()` thing is just ugly. That said, the actual code might be fast, efficient, etc. I just find the API ugly and hard to use.

Comment: @NikolayElenkov: As an API, it sucks. However, that very suckage is why Google can add new capabilities to it without breaking its sucktastic API. They can't do that to HttpClient nearly as easily, as logic is spread out over lots of classes. That's why `HttpURLConnection` is the new official recommendation. At least, that's what I've been told by a few Googlers.

Comment: So I've heard, too. Lots of classes with meaningful names and responsibilities is always better. Adding new capabilities by adding classes is better than adding capabilities by adding yet more methods and magic parameters to a single class. If they have to do more work to achieve that, they should :).

Comment: Ok cool so since I want my code to be fast, efficient, and time-proof, I will use HttpURLConnection. I agree its super ugly having the two streams and dealing with each individually. For me it feels very functional vs object oriented. I also like how HttpURLConnection automatically handles gzip. If any faster improvements are made in future releases they are likely to be transparent saving me time in rewriting the ResponseInterceptor etc. So thats how i justified my decision. Thanks again for all the help.

Comment: HttpURLConnection does suck. If you don't set read / connect timeouts and the remote server is hanging (say, from a Thread.sleep) and your own internet connection goes away briefly, you can have a thread that will not complete and will not go away until you restart your machine. Same thing if the connection to the remote server hang due to high load, and you get SocketException: end of file reached. If you try getInputStream() on the connection after that, it will hang forever. IMO that's pretty unacceptable for enterprise software. HttpURLConnection sucks! Use apache's HTTP client